# Missing or incorrect CSRF cookie type

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 4.1 and also xero api. When the user logs in xero is connected . Sometimes this error appears below. My questions is that how do i prevent this and why is this happening? "The problem is this: If a user has the login page tab several days opened in the browser then the cookie expires and this leads to this exception". This is incorrect as i can leave login page open for days and not get this error. I can't reproduce it . How do i detect this error and ow do i fix it. I thought the answer to the post does not solve my problem

[Catch "Missing or incorrect CSRF cookie type." exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890961/catch-missing-or-incorrect-csrf-cookie-type-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct it should not happen, the way you can reproduce is by manually modifying the cookies from the browser dev tools.

- Steps to do that (Chrome)
- Open dev tools (Right-click and click on inspector)
- Open Application tab
- Switch to cookies (Choose the domain for which you are setting the cookies)
- Change the expires field (to past date).

Comment: I am getting this error in Firefox and i cant get rid of it ? in chrome it works fine. What do i do in this browser?

Comment: almost same instead of Application tab you need to switch to Storage tab to edit cookies.